# Open file from file manager in Android?

Tags: android, xls, internal-storage

How can I give option to the user to select file from file manager? I want to select excel file.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code,

```
 private static final int PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE=3;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 intent.setType("file/*");
 startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: How to open File Manager for specific folder.

Answer (score 1):

Below code useful for open all type of file in android.

1) in `Oncreate()` call

```
public void callIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setType("*/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select a file"), 123);
}
```

2) Add Read and Write Storage permission in andoridManifext  as well as check permission programatically if Android 6.0 or Above

3) After successfully granting permission `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   if (requestCode == 123 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {
            Uri selectedFile = data.getData();
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of other answers have old deprecated methods in it - startActivityForResult and onActivityResult.

For now, valid method to get files from storage:

Java:

```
 private ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> getFilesLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
            new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), result -> {
                if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Intent data = result.getData();
                    sendFiles(data);
                }
            }
    ) {

    }
    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent()
                .setType("*/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        getFilesLauncher.launch(intent);
    });
```

Kotlin:

```
private var getFilesLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> = registerForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
    ) {
        if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val data: Intent = it.data!!
            sendFiles(data)
        }
    }
    button.setOnClickListener
    {
        val intent = Intent()
            .setType("*/*")
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.flags = FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
        getFilesLauncher.launch(intent)
    }
```